# LEFT JOIN + Multiple WHERE Clausules

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join

I'm having troubles writing an SQL Query. I will explain by my SQL query:

```
SELECT p.Code, p.Name, SUM(h.PA = 1) AS PA, SUM(h.PB = 1) AS PB, 
    SUM(h.PG = 1) AS PG, SUM(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'GF') AS GF,
    SUM(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'SB') AS SB, 
    SUM(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'VIA') AS VIA, sum(h.Blanco) AS Blanco
FROM psthostess p
LEFT JOIN `psttodo-uit` h ON h.`Hostess Code` = p.Code
WHERE p.Indienst = 1 AND DATE(h.`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY p.Code, p.Name
```

As you can see I have a WHERE clausule with `Indienst = 1` and `date = today`. I do a `LEFT JOIN` so I get all the fields (also null). I've justed added `AND DATE(h.afgewerkt tablet datum) = CURDATE()`. So before I got 18 rows, now I only get one because he also checks the date.

But I want 18 rows, also the ones with p.Indienst = 1 but without DATE = CURDATE.

How can I do this?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: @Strawberry: What about nielsv's request was unclear to you? I think he explained his problem quite clear.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's unclear to me as to whether or not nielsv wants NULL or 0 as the sum of absent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `AND DATE(h.`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = CURDATE()` to the ON clause:

```
SELECT p.Code, p.Name, SUM(h.PA = 1) AS PA, SUM(h.PB = 1) AS PB, 
    SUM(h.PG = 1) AS PG, SUM(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'GF') AS GF,
    SUM(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'SB') AS SB, 
    SUM(h.GoedkeuringDoorNew = 'VIA') AS VIA, sum(h.Blanco) AS Blanco
FROM psthostess p
LEFT JOIN `psttodo-uit` h ON h.`Hostess Code` = p.Code
AND DATE(h.`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = CURDATE()
WHERE p.Indienst = 1 
GROUP BY p.Code, p.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want all records, also the ones that don't have 'today' as the date, why are you filtering on today in the first place? Just remove that clause, and you're fine. Or, but this is quite ridiculous, as it does the same as removing the extra clause, change the WHERE to:

```
WHERE (p.Indienst = 1 AND DATE(h.`afgewerkt tablet datum`) = CURDATE())
    OR (p.Indienst = 1 AND DATE(h.`afgewerkt tablet datum`) != CURDATE())
```